# How to launch different activities for different content in cast sender app on mini controll click

Tags: android, google-cast

I'm adding google cast support to an app, and I can only target a single activity to launch on mini controller and notification click. I configure it in OptionsProvider subclass like

```
   @Override
    public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context appContext) {

        Log.d(TAG, "getCastOptions: ");

        NotificationOptions notificationOptions = new NotificationOptions.Builder()
                .setTargetActivityClassName(VideoPlayerActivity.class.getName())
                .build();

        CastMediaOptions mediaOptions = new CastMediaOptions.Builder()
                .setNotificationOptions(notificationOptions)
                .setExpandedControllerActivityClassName(VideoPlayerActivity.class.getName())
                .build();

        CastOptions castOptions = new CastOptions.Builder()
                .setReceiverApplicationId(appContext.getString(R.string.app_id))
                .setCastMediaOptions(mediaOptions)
                .build();
        return castOptions;
    }
```

It's ok when I'm playing video, but I also have music in app, and it doesn't have fullscreen controller. So on notification/mini controller click I want to launch VideoPlayerActivity if video is casting and MusicActivity when music is casting.

Can't figure out how to do it, and can't find it out in documentation. I'm not sure if it's possible.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I think this cannot be done with radio button since radio button doesn't drive from ViewGroup

Comment: @PN10 by radio I mean streaming music. I've edited question not to confuse people.

Comment: this might be of your use refer this link https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define one activity, say ProxyActivity, to be your target activity. Then, in that activity, decide if it is a music or video and launch the corresponding activity; the ProxyActivity doesn't do anything more than deciding which one of the two other activities should be launched.

An alternative is to have your target activity be able to adapt to the type of media (i.e. handling both cases in one activity).

Comment: Thanks for advice! Now I save data type to constant, and start different activities from ProxyActivity depends on content type currently playing.